# Pass private key as header in curl PUT returning error for illegal character

Tags: bash, curl, oauth-2.0, sh, apache-pulsar

I have a `.pem` file containing my private key that I need to pass as an authorization header.

I've tried just using the command `$(cat $REPO_ROOT/pulsar/tls/broker/broker.key.pem)` but I'm getting the response: `<h1>Bad Message 400</h1><pre>reason: Illegal character LF=\n</pre>0`

Can I not pass the contents of my `.pem` straight into the header?

```
CLUSTER=standalone
TENANT=sandbox
NAMESPACE=integration_test
AUTHORIZATION=$(cat $REPO_ROOT/pulsar/tls/broker/broker.key.pem)


# Create tenant
curl -L -X PUT "http://localhost:$HOST_PULSAR_PORT/admin/v2/tenants/$TENANT" \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $AUTHORIZATION" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw "{\"allowedClusters\": [\"$CLUSTER\"]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key needs to be carefully secured. You should **never** have to pass it in an HTTP header.

For Pulsar you should be using the private key to generate a JWT token to use in the HTTP header. You can use the following command:

```
bin/pulsar tokens create --private-key file:///path/to/my-private.key \
            --subject test-user
```

The subject of the token should match the authorization role on the Pulsar tenant or namespace. For more details, see https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/security-token-admin/

Comment: my public key is a .der. Do I need to decode this to use it? or can I cat it to pass it for auth purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Private keys are never meant to be sent as a header in a web request. Perhaps the public key.

When you try to send this:

```
Authorization: Bearer $AUTHORIZATION
```

I suspect you should send a signed JWT token instead?

Also, you try to send a pem file, as application/json, that does not match either. A pem file is typically a multi-line data structure and that needs to be encoded to be able to be sent in a header.